# How to repeatedly insert elements into a sorted list fast

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, data-structures, simulation

I do not have formal CS training, so bear with me.

I need to do a simulation, which can abstracted away to the following (omitting the details):

> We have a list of real numbers representing the times of events. In
>   each step, we
>
> 1. remove the first event, and
> 2. as a result of "processing" it, a few other events may get inserted into the list at a strictly later time
>
> and repeat this many times.

**Questions**

What data structure / algorithm can I use to implement this as efficiently as possible?  I need to increase the number of events/numbers in the list significantly.  The priority is to make this as fast as possible for a long list.

Since I'm doing this in C++, what data structures are already available in the STL or boost that will make it simple to implement this?

---

**More details:**

The number of events in the list is variable, but it's guaranteed to be between `n` and `2*n` where `n` is some simulation parameter.  While the event times are increasing, the time-difference of the latest and earliest events is also guaranteed to be less than a constant `T`.  Finally, I suspect that the density of events in time, while not constant, also has an upper and lower bound (i.e. all the events will never be strongly clustered around a single point in time)

**Efforts so far:**

As the title of the question says, I was thinking of using a sorted list of numbers.  If I use a linked list for constant time insertion, then I have trouble finding the position where to insert new events in a fast (sublinear) way.

Right now I am using an approximation where I divide time into buckets, and keep track of how many event are there in each bucket.  Then process the buckets one-by-one as time "passes", always adding a new bucket at the end when removing one from the front, thus keeping the number of buckets constant.  This is fast, but only an approximation.

Comment: Choosing a data structure depends on what kind of data you want to store in it as well as what operations you will perform on the data structure.

Comment: Do all events have a unique timestamp, and what format is the time in?

Comment: @Als I just spent 20 minutes writing all that up ... it's all in the question

Comment: @KerrekSB for each event I need to store the timestap (double or float) and the type (there are only a few types, currently 2, so this can be an enum)

Comment: @KerrekSB It's not guaranteed that all timestamps are unique.  With a tiny probability two events may get the same timestamp.

Comment: How large is `n`? 10, 1000, 1000000000?

Comment: @Szabolcs: How are you going to access the data structure? Are you going to write only at ends? Are you going to need to access elements randomly? What is the data format?

Comment: Well, I was thinking of a `multimap<K, V>`, where `K` is a type that represents your timestamp -- but if you use floating point numbers, you have to consider whether you'll be able get predictable timestamps, or whether you perform any computations on the timestamps that may not be accurate.

Comment: @ViktorDahl I don't know yet how large I'll need for good results (physics simulation).  Currently the aim is to get it as large as possible: at least 10000 then add orders of magnitude.

Comment: `std::priority_queue` would be my first choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A min-heap might suit your needs. There's an [explanation here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) and I think STL provides the `priority_queue` for you.

Insertion time is O(log N), removal is O(log N)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need/want a priority queue. If memory serves, the priority queue adapter in the standard library is written to retrieve the largest items instead of the smallest, so you'll have to specify that it use `std::greater` for comparison.

Other than that, it provides just about exactly what you've asked for: the ability to quickly access/remove the smallest/largest item, and the ability to insert new items quickly. While it doesn't maintain all the items in order, it does maintain enough order that it can still find/remove the one smallest (or largest) item quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with a basic priority queue, and see if that's fast enough.
If not, then you can look at writing something custom.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Answer (score 2):

A binary tree is always sorted and has faster access times than a linear list. Search, insert and delete times are O(log(n)).

But it depends whether the items have to be sorted all the time, or only after the process is finished. In the latter case a hash table is probably faster. At the end of the process you then would copy the items to an array or a list and sort it.